# How should I rsync files in /var/www if I want them to be owned by www-data?

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, rsync, chown

I have set up a new ec2 ubuntu box and installed apache and php5. By default you log onto the box with the `ubuntu` user who has `sudo` privileges.

I believe apache runs as `root` and php5 runs as `www-data`.

I think that I want all of the files in `/var/www` to be chown'ed to `www-data:www-data`, and folders set as 755 and files as 644 - unless there is an issue with that.

Things run fine like this, but my issue is that when I `rsync` files from my laptop to the server it changes the ownership on them (and adds new files) as `ubuntu:admin`

I have been through the `rsync` manual and searched Google, and I've seen a syntax like:

```
rsync -avzcO (source) (destination) --owner=www-data --group=www-data
```

However it appears that `--owner` and `--group` don't not take an argument but instead are meant to be used to force the remote files to have the same owner as on the local file system if rsync is being done as a super user.

So, I haven't found a solution with rsync to set the remote user and group of files during rsync.

**What am I doing wrong?**

Thoughts:

- Maybe my files in /var/www should just be owned by `ubuntu:admin` ?
- Maybe I have the rsync syntax wrong
- I guess I could rsync as the `www-data` user but that doesn't seem like a good idea
- I could use suPHP like I would do on a shared host, but that seems like quite a bit of trouble

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't want them owned by www-data. Apache initially runs as root and then drops privileges to www-data. You don't want your web content writable by the user that owns the apache processes. This creates a security vulnerability.

In the event that Apache is breeched, ideally the www-data user will have no access to any of the system. This is the most secure configuration. If the web content is owned by www-data, if Apache is breeched then the attacker can overwrite any of your web content.

Your web content should be owned by a normal user (this excludes `nobody`, `www-data` and `root`). Only things that *need* to be writable by Apache should be owned by www-data.

Comment: So then it being owned by `ubuntu:admin` would be an acceptable practice? And if I am running something like wordpress then then `uploads` folder could be either `chmod 777` or owned by `www-data` - right?

Comment: Yes, that's right. I would make the uploads either owned by root:root and mode `1777` or owned by root:www-data and mode `1775`.